# Is it possible to prevent an android Activity from being stopped when other Activities are being started?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-management

I'm creating an Android app, and I want one of my Activities to keep running until the user presses the back-button when just that Activity is open.
Currently, that Activity is being stopped as the app starts other Activities, but **I wonder if it is possible to prevent that Activity to stop when the app need more memory or something alike?**

This example describes my problem:

I have five Activities, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`. Activity `C` is the one I want to prevent from being stopped. The Activity named `A` is the main menu of the app which starts first of all.

The user starts the app, which launches Activity `A`.
The second Activity, `B`, is started by the user with a click on one of the buttons in the menu.
The user browses a file and clicks on it, which launches the third Activity, `C`. The user clicks an item in a list which display data from the file. This starts Activity `D`. The user looks around at the data, and clicks another item in a list in that Activity to get more detailed information about that data. This starts Activity `E`. Now, Activity `C` is also being stopped. This causes some problems, so I need to keep it running.

Comment: try using service and do your work in it ...

Comment: @quicklearner This doesn't really work for what I need. I need to prevent the `onStop()` method from being called until the user manually backs out of the `Activity`. I have some code in that method that I want to execute only then. In other words, I want to prevent the `Activity` from getting stopped due to memory freeing or something like that. But thanks for the suggestion! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, I solved this by putting the work causing trouble in its own `Service`, to make it keep running in the background even though activities got killed and re-created.